# Got exception when i try to replace a Mutable Array item

Tags: objective-c, ios

i got this exception:

```
[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

when i try to replace a specific element by another:

**EDIT:**
this is my whole code:

```
//declaring an AppDelegate instance
    AppDelegate *myAppDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    //get the array in which we have stored all the choosed themes
    NSMutableArray *aMutableArray=myAppDelegate.themesChoosed;


    for (int i=0; i<[aMutableArray count]; i++) {
            NSString *str=[NSString stringWithString:[aMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            if ([str isEqualToString:@"B1"]) {
                [aMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"B2"];
          }
    }
```

I maked sure that the `B1` element does exist in the array.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening to your NSMuatbleArray before you get into the `for` loop?

Is it a property? If so, what is the property declaration? Did you use `copy`?

If you implement a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

...then you can run into problems like this because the synthesized setter sends `copy` to the array, which results in an immutable copy. If this is the case, you need to implement your own setter that calls `mutableCopy` on the array (or just use `retain` instead and design your code a little differently).

EDIT:

Based on your comments below and the updated code, I'm sure the problem must be something to do with the array on the app delegate not being mutable.

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableThemeseChoosed = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myAppDelegate.themesChoosed];
```

Comment: I didn't implement a property for that array, i just define it when i need: `NSMutableArray *aMutableArray=anotherMutableArray;`, should i property it? i am using the  ARC.

Comment: There's no reason that you should need a property for this to work. Have you tried the above with a new muableArray that isn't from 'anotherMutableArray'?

Comment: Perhaps if you updated the question with more of your code, we might be able to spot something wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, that was all my code, it's independent of the other code. my `NSMutableArray` contain the word `B1` which i want to replace it y the word `B2`

Comment: There must be more than that surely? There isn't even a declaration or assignment of your problem array above. Perhaps paste the whole method?

Comment: I have edited my post, `themesChoosed`is a global `NSMutableArray`

Comment: @Malek well, your application does not agree with this, so maybe you could show us how do you create this array, and how is it assigned to appDelegate.themesChoosed?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it works fine.

```
NSMutableArray *aMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithString:@"A1"],[NSString stringWithString:@"B1"],[NSString stringWithString:@"B2"],[NSString stringWithString:@"A1"],[NSString stringWithString:@"A2"],[NSString stringWithString:@"A1"],[NSString stringWithString:@"A1"], nil];

NSLog(@"%@",aMutableArray);

for (int i=0; i<[aMutableArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithString:[aMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"B1"]) {
        [aMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"B2"];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",aMutableArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is - as the error tells - that your *mutable* array is a `NSArray` (which is **not** mutable)

What you get out of `myAppDelegate.themesChoosed;` is likely a NSArray. Try the following: `NSMutableArray *aMutableArray= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myAppDelegate.themesChoosed];`